# How to limit the user to input b/w a range in Python

Tags: python

I wrote this program to take input from user and create a dictionary and later check user's inputs to see if the keys exist in the created dictionary. So, the program works just fine but when the n's value is greater than 10ˆ5 it gives me a runtime error or EOFError. I tried using `try:` `except:` method. But not really sure if I used it the right way. I need to restrict the user from entering the value of n to 1<= n <= 10ˆ5. All suggestions are appreciated! Thank you

```
n = int(input())
phoneBook = dict(input().split() for _ in range(n))
for i in range(n):
    string = str(input())
    if string in phoneBook:
        print("{}={}".format(string,phoneBook[string]))
    else :
         print("Not found")
```

Comment: what about using [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) as in  `range(max(n, SOME_MAX_VALUE))`?

Comment: if statement if the input is in that range?

Comment: There's no reason for this to give you EOFError, unless you're not passing enough lines after passing `n`. are you redirecting the input from a file or something ?

Comment: simply cehck if n>10**5:return  else:perform task

Comment: @Maddy Its actually a challenge on a website and I'm passing all the test cases except one and that test case fails cuz it passes n=10ˆ5

Comment: Usually the online problems simply tell you the limits of the input so you can chose the appropriate data types / structures. Preventing an input value likely wont make a single case pass. Your code might timeout for the problem given because you are looping over a large N value twice.